# PHP ORM inheritance workaround?

Tags: php, database, inheritance, orm, mapping

I'm building a web app and would like to use an ORM to map the data from db with objects.
I have been struggling with this for a few days, and tried various implementations, including: *Codeigniter ORM, Kohana ORM, PHP.ActiveRecords and Doctrine*.
The last two I can't really use, because they depend on PHP 5.3 which is not installed (and can not be) on my shared hosting server.

The problem with all these ORM-s is inheritance (except for Doctrine, but I can' use it).
I know a lot of developers just do db-s without inheritance, but here is my problem:

My db needs to be multilingual, I designed my db by the following example:
Table `Product -> id, category_id, price...` (everything that is not translatable)
Table `ProductTranslation-> id, language_id, name, description...` (same id as product, adds language FK, and fields that are translatable)

Maybe there is a better approach, but I really like this, because its very flexible (can add new languages) and does not put a lot of *NULL-s* in the db, also joining is not that costly because the tables are relatively small (unlike the approach to put all translations in a single table, and reference that table from all other tables).

The only workaround, I found,  to support ORMs is to put a `has_one` relation between
`Product->ProductTranslation`.

This way I could access the translated fields with something like:
`DB::get_product_by_id(4)->translation->name`

Nevermind the syntax, but the real problem with this approach is that I have to define new objects(models) for translation tables, and logically they don't belong there. They are not entities, just additional data for the entities.

So, my question here are:

- Is there a better way to organize languages in the db, which is more *ORM friendly* ?
- Are there any other PHP ORM-s (<5.3) which support inheritance ? - Btw. I found the [Kohana ORM ihertiance module](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/orm-inheritance) but it seems out-of-date, and doesn't work with the current framework version
- Are there any other workaround for the inheritance problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine 2.0 requires PHP 5.3, but [Doctrine 1.2.x](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/en) works fine on PHP 5.2.3 or newer.

Comment: Doctrine 1.2.x is great! Thanks for the suggestion. It still can't handle multiple db tables without having to define a model class for each one, but I guess I'll have to live with that, and make classes for everything. At least it has proper inheritance, unlike the majority of other ORMs

Comment: Just to add, after reading some documentation, doctrine has a build in I18n behavior, which does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot! Doctrine is the way to go with this

Answer (score 1):

why not use [Propel's i18n behavior](http://propel.posterous.com/propel-gets-i18n-behavior-and-why-it-matters) ?